# Silverlight 4 DataGrid border around a column

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, silverlight-4.0, border

I haven't been able to find anyway to dynamically add a border around a column in a silverlight datagrid. Here is my xaml of my datagrid:

```
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="PlannedAndBookedMonthlyTable" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="5,0,5,5">
   <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
      <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="MonthlyHeaderName" Header="" Binding="{Binding SeriesName}" />
      <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="MonthlyHeaderJan" Header="Jan" Binding="{Binding JanValue}" />
      <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="MonthlyHeaderFeb" Header="Feb" Binding="{Binding FebValue}" />
      <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="MonthlyHeaderMar" Header="Mar" Binding="{Binding MarValue}" />
      <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="MonthlyHeaderApr" Header="Apr" Binding="{Binding AprValue}" />
      <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="MonthlyHeaderMay" Header="May" Binding="{Binding MayValue}" />
      <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="MonthlyHeaderJun" Header="Jun" Binding="{Binding JunValue}" />
      <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="MonthlyHeaderJul" Header="Jul" Binding="{Binding JulValue}" />
      <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="MonthlyHeaderAug" Header="Aug" Binding="{Binding AugValue}" />
      <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="MonthlyHeaderSep" Header="Sep" Binding="{Binding SepValue}" />
      <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="MonthlyHeaderOct" Header="Oct" Binding="{Binding OctValue}" />
      <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="MonthlyHeaderNov" Header="Nov" Binding="{Binding NovValue}" />
      <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="MonthlyHeaderDec" Header="Dec" Binding="{Binding DecValue}" />
      <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="MonthlyHeaderTotal" Header="Total" Binding="{Binding Total}" />
   </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

This is the effect that I want to accomplish:

[image]

How do I set the border on a column of data that depends on what current calendar month it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each row in a DataGrid is a template, as is each cell. The normal DataGrid has no concept of cells and current cell positions, just selected rows.

If you were able to get enough positional information I would say you could overlay a border over the DataGrid, but the debugger shows me there is not enough information available in a DataGrid to even calculate the position of the current selected cell.

### One possible option

The only way I can think of doing this with a DataGrid is catching focus events on the individual cell controls (e.g. TextBoxes in the DataGrid) and use the position of the selected control *relative to the parent* to work out the border position. Each column will need to be a templated column so that you can hook up the GotFocus events.

### Otherwise...

...you will need to try a different sort of control to get the result you are seeking.

You could use a plain old Grid, e.g. full of TextBox controls, but you will need to handle selection and keyboard navigation of the grid yourself.

If budget permits, I would look around for a 3rd party spreadsheet control for Silverlight. Otherwise see if anyone has built one on Codeplex or elsewhere.

Comment: I had to go the route of using a plain old Grid to achieve the desired look. Thanks for the input.